# Не могу сохранить рисунок в БД с его измененными размерами

Tags: delphi, firebird, interbase

Есть БД и форма на которой находится компоненты *TMyDBImage* (просматривает рисунки из БД) и *TImage* ит.д.
Происходит загрузка картинки в *TImage* и изменение ее размера на необходимые.
Далее с помощью потока перезаписываю ее в поле типа “*blob*”, все замечательно.

```
Var
  qq: TMemoryStream;

begin
…
  StretchBlt (Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, r2.Right, r2.Bottom, Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, r1.Right, r1.Bottom, SRCCOPY);
  qq := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.SaveToStream(qq);
  qq.Position := 0;
  TBlobField(ibdsFeatures.FieldByName('VOICE_IMAGE')).LoadFromStream(qq);
```

Но при просмотре картинки в «*TMyDBImage*», **размеры картинки остались такими, как и до изменения**.

В чем может быть ошибка?

P.S. Размер *TImage* такой же как и у *TMyDBImage*. По *TImage* подбирается конкретный размер.

Comment: Обновить данные в `TMyDBImage`  после сохранения не пробовали?

Comment: @Streletz, ... пробывал, даже перегружал программу. Ничего не помогает

Comment: а в бд точно пишется? не забываешь сделать commit ?

Comment: "Sultanov Shamil, ха-ха... по моему я на этот вопрос в коментарии выше (от вашего коментария) ответил... И к тому же каритинка после перегрузки программы в *TMyDBImage* отображается.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите внимательно, что делает эта строчка:

```
StretchBlt(Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, r2.Right, r2.Bottom, 
  Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, r1.Right, r1.Bottom, SRCCOPY);
```

Что вы передаете в качестве выходного HDC? Что такое `Canvas.Handle`? Чей это `Canvas`? Если вы хотите изменить исходный битмап, то нужно делать это так:

```
StretchBlt(Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, r2.Right, r2.Bottom, 
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, r1.Right, r1.Bottom, SRCCOPY);
Image1.Picture.Bitmap.SetSize(r1.Right, r1.Bottom);
```

А уж только потом:

```
qq := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.SaveToStream(qq);
  ...
finally
  qq.Free;
end;
```